# is class with only one instance considered a singleton if it doesn't have global scope?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I'm reading about a singletons and it's mentioned everywhere that singletons are not good since they have global scope. What if I have a class with only one instance but it can't be accessed globally instead it should be injected as a dependency - is the class still a singleton?

Comment: Who said that singletons may not have a local scope? Are you sure you aren't confusing them with global variables?

Comment: They can, I guess. But my question is based on [this](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars/) article and specifically this line _Singletons are nothing more than global state. Global state makes it so your objects can secretly get hold of things which are not declared in their APIs, and, as a result, Singletons make your APIs into pathological liars._

Comment: global state != global scope. You can have global state with private but static values as well, the singleton doesn't need to be assigned to a global variable for that. Of course, whether this is bad depends on whether you use the singleton for state or not.

Comment: I might be an idiot, but aren't singletons characterized by the fact that there is only one instance for that particular class? What does that have to do with scope?

Comment: Whosoever wrote that article is a pathological liar. Also I'm not even sure whether that article was talking about JavaScript. Singletons are not global state.

Comment: @Bergi, thanks. Do you know any good resource to read about what is global state and its the difference from global scope?

Comment: Hm, [Wikipedia disagrees with me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_state_(computing)). I had considered "global state" to be a synonym for "state of the whole application", but apparently it's often used to describe state that is stored in global variables (or fields of singletons in global variables, for that matter) which can be *modified from everywhere*. "global scope" is just the lexical scope in which global variables reside, but as long as those are referentially transparent functions, constructors or constants, there's nothing inherently wrong with it.

Comment: @Bergi, so what about my question `is class with only one instance considered a singleton if it doesn't have global scope`? I'm asking this because everywhere I read singletons are mentioned as being globally accessible.

Comment: Yes, a "class with only one instance" is basically the definition of a singleton. In many languages however classes are static (can't be created dynamically) and are globally accessible - in javascript that doesn't need to be the case.

Comment: Thanks! Does that _classes are static (can't be created dynamically) and are globally accessible_ apply to C++?

Comment: As far as I know, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer to my own question - quote from [here](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-brittle-global-state-singletons/):

`When we say “Singleton” or “JVM Singleton” in this document, we mean the classic Gang of Four singleton. (We say that this singleton enforces its own “singletonness” through a static instance field). An “application singleton” on the other hand is an object which has a single instance in our application, but which does not enforce its own “singletonness.”`

So basically they distinguish between two different types of singleton classes.